# CommittedItemChanges event in muddatagrid Does not work

Tags: mudblazor

I am currently using muddatagrid to edit my data. When I use mudcheckbox in the EditTemplate tag to edit bool data, the CommittedItemChanges event does not work. While the other data is edited correctly. For this purpose, I have coded I created it in the link below. Please check it and explain it if there is any problem
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mOGROMvUnzRzWmiE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MudDataGrid` Currently does not support boolean types.
They seem to be working on that feature.

https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/pull/7093

`CommittedItemChanges` does get triggered when using the `EditMode=DataGridEditMode.Form` Form edit mode. However, it's best to not use it until that type is fully supported.