# Select check SelectColumn from a MudDataGrid when loading data

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, mudblazor

I am using the examples provided in the official documentation, but I cannot select the check according to the data loaded. In the example model I have a column called isActive which should select or deselect the box depending on its value.

```
 public class ModelChannel
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Sign { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public int Molar { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

<MudDataGrid T="ModelChannel" MultiSelection="true" Items="@Elements" SortMode="SortMode.Multiple" Filterable="true" QuickFilter="@_quickFilter"
    Hideable="true" RowClick="@RowClicked" RowContextMenuClick="RowRightClicked" SelectedItemsChanged="@SelectedItemsChanged">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Periodic Elements</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="_searchString" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" Immediate="true"
                      AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
    </ToolBarContent>
    <Columns>
        <SelectColumn />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Number" Title="Nr" Sortable="false" Filterable="false"/>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Sign" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" SortBy="@_sortBy" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Position" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Molar" Title="Molar mass" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Group" Title="Category" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.IsActive" Title="Active" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudDataGridPager T="ModelChannel" />
    </PagerContent>
</MudDataGrid>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFipm.png)

I have tried to find the SelectColumn property that allows me to assign the value received in the data, I hope you can help me find a solution to this issue since there is not much information

Comment: MudDataGrid does not support Boolean properties at the moment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76913221/11779494

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `@bind-SelectedItems` property to the MudDataGrid and bind an HashSet that you can populate based on the "IsActive" property. For example:

```
<MudDataGrid T="ModelChannel" Items="@Elements" SortMode="SortMode.Multiple" Filterable="true"
         MultiSelection=true @bind-SelectedItems="selectedItems">
<ToolBarContent>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Periodic Elements</MudText>
    <MudSpacer />
</ToolBarContent>
<Columns>
    <SelectColumn />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Number" Title="Nr" Sortable="false" Filterable="false" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Sign" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Position" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Molar" Title="Molar mass" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Group" Title="Category" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.IsActive" Title="Active" />
</Columns>
<PagerContent>
    <MudDataGridPager T="ModelChannel" />
</PagerContent>
```

And OnInitialized:

```
private HashSet<ModelChannel> selectedItems = new();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");

    foreach (var item in Elements)
    {
        if (item.IsActive)
        {
            selectedItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias eeemanueeeleee